# heroku toolbelt `initialize': no implicit conversion of nil into Hash (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I checked my system updates it shows that both heroku and heroku toolbelt updated , but after that i got this error

```
heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/common.rb:67:in `initialize': no implicit conversion of nil into Hash (TypeError)
```

m not able to run any heroku commands. Previously it was working fine but now it's not.

heroku, heroku-versions  3.9.4, previously it was 3.9.1

```
 xxxxx@xxxxx:~$ heroku 
/usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/common.rb:67:in `initialize': no implicit conversion of nil into Hash (TypeError)
    from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/common.rb:67:in `new'
    from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/common.rb:67:in `generator='
    from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/ext.rb:17:in `<module:Ext>'
    from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/ext.rb:12:in `<module:JSON>'
    from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/ext.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/akaruilabs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/akaruilabs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json.rb:58:in `<module:JSON>'
    from /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json.rb:54:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/akaruilabs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/akaruilabs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/akaruilabs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/akaruilabs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: provide version of the `toolbelt`

Comment: It seems in your code somewhere you are trying to convert a JSON to Hash and that JSON is nil.Show the full error.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ added the version

Comment: have you updated the `heroku-toolbelt`, if yes, try then update `json`

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ with gem update json ..???? or bundle update..?

Comment: save your current `Gemfile.lock`, then try `bundle update`

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ done with no success...

Comment: Please see https://status.heroku.com/incidents/650

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've same error. Note, that `json` library that produces error is not from your gems but comes with a heroku toolbelt distirbution. So updating `json` is not enough and I think that this should be reported to heroku as a bug.

My workaround for this moment is to install a fresh `json` gem and remove its stale version `1.7.7` from heroku toolbelt:

```
gem install json
sudo mv /usr/local/heroku/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7 /some/tmp
gem list json
  *** LOCAL GEMS ***
  json (1.8.1)
heroku version
  heroku-toolbelt/3.9.4 (x86_64-linux) ruby/2.1.1
```

**UPDATE:** Seems like this issue was fixed in `3.9.5`

Answer (score 0):

When committing to Heroku, I got:

```
/app/vendor/lpxc/lpxc.rb:94: [BUG] hooks/pre-receive:99:in `exit': no implicit conversion from nil to integer (TypeError)
    from hooks/pre-receive:99:in `<main>'
```

I solved it by running `bundle install` locally, and commit the updated `Gemfile.lock` to Heroku too.