# Having trouble with pushing to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, heroku

When I type in the command line heroku run rake db:migrate in the Nitrous.IO.
This is what it shows in the console.:-( Very frustrated.

```
action@naomi-box-1-129907:~/pinteresting(master*)$ heroku run rake db:migrate 
/home/action/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/common.rb:67:in `initialize': no implicit conversion of nil into Hash (TypeError) 
from /home/action/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/common.rb:67:in `new' 
from /home/action/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/common.rb:67:in `generator=' 
from /home/action/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/ext.rb:17:in `<module:Ext>' 
from /home/action/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/ext.rb:12:in `<module:JSON>' 
from /home/action/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json/ext.rb:9:in `<top (required)>' 
from /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require' 
from /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require' 
from /home/action/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json.rb:58:in `<module:JSON>' 
from /home/action/.heroku/client/vendor/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json.rb:54:in `<top (required)>' 
from /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require' 
from /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require' 
from /home/action/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:18:in `<top (required)>' 
from /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require' 
from /home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require' 
from /home/action/.parts/bin/heroku:22:in `<main>'
```

Is there something I can do to fix this? Or should I just create another box and redo everything?

Comment: try forcing an update of the Heroku client with `heroku update`

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work. ：（

Comment: Any chance you skipped rake db:create?

Comment: I just checked,rake db:create                                                                                                                                   
db/development.sqlite3 already exists                                                                                                                                                              
db/test.sqlite3 already exists . Still don't know the problem yet.:(

Comment: Did you add pg gem to your gemfile?

Comment: Yes, I think it might be the ruby and rails verison problem. Because heroku doesn't support 2.1.1

Comment: This is all on your local machine/nitrous not Heroku's side. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881973/heroku-toolbelt-initialize-no-implicit-conversion-of-nil-into-hash-typeerror as to a fix.